# Should one use unit tests for a given code block only when it's too complicated for Integration tests?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing

We have this question from quite sometime and often surface time to time, with a lot of arguments. The system we develop we make it a practice to create unit tests at the different layers (Workers and Controllers/Presenters) mocking the subsequent layer and at the same time we create integration tests at the presenter / controller level.

Imagine following scenario,

**Repositories**

```
UserRepository
{
      User GetByUserName(string username);
}

OrderRepository
{
       List<Order> FindForUser(int userId);
}
```

**Workers**

```
UserOrderWorker
{
        //constructor injected
        UserRepository _userRepo;
        OrderRepository _orderRepo;

       IList<Order> FindOrders(string userName)
       {
                var user = _userRepo.GetByUserName(userName);
                return _orderRepo.FindForUser(user.Id);        
       }
}
```

**Controller**

```
UserOrderController
{
       View _view;
       //constructor injected
       UserOrderWorker _worker;

       void Index()
       {
                _view.Orders = _worker. FindOrders(_view.UserName);
       }
}
```

If we are to create unit tests for worker by mocking the both UserRepository and OrderRepository. Also we create unit test for the UserOrderController by mocking both the view and UserOrderController. So to cover this we need 3 unit tests and also we need 2 integration tests against the repositories. So end of the day it's 5 tests total.

On the other hand if we are to create integration test for this, we only need to create one for the UserOrderController.

For the arguments of using the integration test only,

1. If the actual usage of the application is considered user would only use the Controller and integration test would cover the end user's scenarios.
2. If there is a change done in the middle layer (say if only orders with certain status is fetched by changing repository method `FindForUser(int userId)` to `FindForUser(int userId,List<Status> statuses))`, there would be minimal changes needs to be done in the integration test (addition of extra order outside the accepted statuses), where most of the tests needs to be changed in unit tests (2 tests needs changing and more tests needs to be added.

For arguments of using unit tests only,

1. You can point the failure faster – however, most of the time the failure would be due to changing of the method signature (since someone forgot to configure mock objects)
2. Better documentation – well documentation from the integration test should be good enough to identify the customer requirement, and in my opinion it's good enough.

With all above is considered, I am not sure why we actually need unit tests when we can actually get much better results by using integration tests. (of course someone might say integration tests are expensive, but I would say it's not expensive as developer hours spent on modifying unit tests when business requirement changes)

Comment: Belongs at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Relevant question from Programmers:  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/204786/53019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit tests and integration tests serve different purposes:

- with unit tests you verify whether given component **works as intended**
- with integration tests you verify whether a group of components **works together**, without verifying specific components details

Your case is extremely trivial and unit tests might not offer much over one decent integration tests for `UserOrderController`. But this is only because your classes are very small and contain no complicated logic.

However, what happens when `UserOrderWorker` gets more complicated?

- what if `_userRepo` returns null because no user was found?
- what if `_userRepo` throws exception because connection to database timed out?
- what if new requirement is introduced saying that for specific users (parents) you need to also extract its children orders?

To test such scenarios with integration tests you would have to have separate test for each specific case. Multiplied by number of components participating in integration test. This is usually too much. Unit tests not only help you mitigate this problem but also, due to their nature, are able to pinpoint failure location more precisely.

Comment: Exactly my point, when 'unit tests might not offer much over one decent integration tests ', should we go straight for the integration test and get rid of unit tests / not write them at all? In my case this will easily eliminate 50% of unit tests and code base would be much smaller.

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican: I would say yes. When classes only forward db entities (like in your case), it's better to cover them with few, use case-wide integration tests rather than unit testing whether method A called mocked method B. You lose nothing (got integration test and decent coverage), and once logic gets more complicated nothing stops you from adding unit tests to certain components while still maintaining integration tests for larger use case.

Answer (score 1):

your example is too simple to be representative. there is no complex logic in that code. when you have a lot of ifs and loops then it changes.

let's say you have n `if` statements in your application. this means you have 2^n possible distinct execution flows. so you can test each `if` with with 2 unit tests, therefore you have 2n unit tests. or you can do only integration tests. but then you need 2^n tests.

loops complicates the problem even more. therefore when you have no logic (getters/setters/sequences) then maybe you don't need any tests at all. but when you have complex logic then maybe it's better to test that complex thing in isolation

another thing is difficulty of integration testing. for example you want to test your code that runs only at the end of year. it's easier to prepare environment (like time) in unit tests then in integration tests where you should not interfere as much with system's internals